# What is crontab directory path?

Tags: cron

Guys i am testing if cron runs correctly in my docker debian container.

I've set up crontab

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "it works!" >> test.log
```

But i can't find this file anywhere.

I tried

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "it works!" >> /var/log/test.log
```

not luck too.

What is ">>" function's writes to path?

Answer (score 2):

> '>>' redirects output to a file appending the redirected output at the end.

So it should be in /var/log/test.log

Your error should be in the cron settings.

[This](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) link really helped me the beginnnig